# Implementing sitemaps in Django

Tags: python, django, sitemap

I'm having a problem implementing the sitemaps in my application. I'm using Virtualenv, django 1.4 and Python 2.7. I would appreciate if you can help me resolve this.

This is what I have done:

1. In my urls.py

   ```
   from sitemap import JobPostSitemap
   sitemaps = { 
       'jobs': JobPostSitemap, 
   }
   ... # Removed other urls
   url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
   ```
2. Then in my sitemap.py file

   ```
   from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
   from jobs.models import JobPost

   class JobPostSitemap(Sitemap):
       changefreq = "never"
       priority = 0.5

       def items(self):
           return JobPost.objects.filter(approved=True)

       def lastmod(self, obj):
           return obj.pub_date
   ```
3. My settings.py file is as follows:

   ```
   TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
       'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
       'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
   )
   ...
   INSTALLED_APPS = ( 
       'django.contrib.auth', 
       'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
       'django.contrib.sessions', 
       'django.contrib.sites', 
       'django.contrib.messages', 
       'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
       'django.contrib.sitemaps', 
       'jobs', 
   )
   ...
   ```

Now when I open my browser and navigate to `http://localhost:8000/sitemap.xml` , I get the following error:

```
ImportError at /sitemap.xml

No module named django.contrib.sitemaps
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/sitemap.xml
Django Version: 1.4.2
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named django.contrib.sitemaps
Exception Location: /home/frank/Projects/python/django/techjobsea.com/baseline27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /home/frank/Projects/python/django/techjobsea.com/baseline27/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

I can't figure out what I've missed or doing wrong.

Comment: Have you followed all the required installation steps for `sitemap`? The required steps [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/)

Comment: @doru Yes. I followed the all the steps.

Comment: @MuratÇorlu No, I didn't. Can't explain why its not working.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had similar error. I changed urls.py definition like that:

```
from sitemap import JobPostSitemap
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
sitemaps = { 
    'jobs': JobPostSitemap, 
}
... # Removed other urls
url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
```

and It worked for me. I don't know why...

Comment: Dude, this actually worked. Thanks. I will be interested to know why this works as opposed to the other method. Sweeet!

Comment: Did the `patterns` call have a non-empty `prefix` parameter? Something like `urlpatterns = patterns('some.prefix', url(r'...'), ....)`? This could have been your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a `PYTHONPATH` issue. Run `python manage.py shell` and try to `import django.contrib.sitemaps`

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably lies in the url.py config that you have not wholly submitted. In my case I had inadvertently left a prefix of the form: `urlpatterns = patterns('...')` that prevented Django from finding the right path.

Comment: Thanks, but I have included that section. All the urls work fine except the sitemap.

Answer (score -2):

To activate sitemap generation on your Django site, add this line to your URLconf:

```
(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps})
```

This tells Django to build a sitemap when a client accesses /sitemap.xml.